# Convertir una cadena de tipo string y convertirlo en un array JSON

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json

Estoy  obteniendo los elementos de una tabla que tengan `check` y  se serializan como JSON mediante `JSON.stringify` y se pasan como datos en la solicitud Ajax, posterior mi `action` recibe estos datos y los debería convertir directamente a una cadena JSON en un objeto JSONArray para posteriormente insertarlos en mi tabla mediante mi método `DAO insertPago`, pero por alguna razón no logro convertir mi `String detalleacopioJson` en un arreglo JSON.

**Mi action:**

```
private String detalleacopioJson;
public String getDetalleacopioJson() {
  return detalleacopioJson;
}
  public void setDetalleacopioJson(String detalleacopioJson) {
  this.detalleacopioJson = detalleacopioJson;
}

public String insertAcpiosTrados() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("HOLA");
  System.out.println("HOLA 2" + getDetalleacopioJson());
  JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(detalleacopioJson);
    JSONArray detalleacopioArray = json.getJSONArray("detalleacopio");
    // Llamar al método DAO para insertar los elementos seleccionados
    ModeloAcopios mabier = new ModeloAcopios();
    for (int i = 0; i < detalleacopioArray.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject acJson = detalleacopioArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Acopios ac = (Acopios) JSONObject.toBean(acJson, Acopios.class);
        mabier.insertPago(ac);
      System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Mi script en javaScript:**

```
 <script>
  var elementosSeleccionados = [];
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#laboratorio').DataTable({
      "pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, "Todo"]
      ],
      responsive: true,
      dom: 'lBfrtip',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: '<strong>Registrar</strong>',
          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

            if (elementosSeleccionados.length > 0) {


              // Enviar los elementos seleccionados al servidor
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "insertAcpiosTrados.action",
                data: { detalleacopioJson: JSON.stringify({ detalleacopio: elementosSeleccionados }) },
                //data: {  detalleacopioJson: JSON.stringify(elementosSeleccionados)},
                success: function (response) {

                  Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Éxito',
                    text: 'Se han enviado exitosamente ' + elementosSeleccionados.length + ' elementos'
                  }).then(function () {
                    alert(response.status);     //location.href = 'perfil.php';
                  });
                },
                error: function () {
                  alert(response.status);
                  alert(detalleacopioJson);
                  alert(JSON.stringify({ detalleacopio: elementosFiltrados }));
                  Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'Error al enviar el correo'
                  });
                }
              });
            } else {
              Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'No se ha seleccionado ningún elemento',
                footer: '<a href="">Why do I have this issue?</a>'
              });
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Buscar Registros",
      }
    });

    var table = $('#laboratorio').DataTable();

    // Manejar el evento de cambio de selección
    $('#laboratorio tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
      var valor = $(this).val();

      if (this.checked) {
        // Agregar el valor a la lista de elementos seleccionados
        elementosSeleccionados.push(valor);
      } else {
        // Remover el valor de la lista de elementos seleccionados
        var index = elementosSeleccionados.indexOf(valor);
        if (index > -1) {
          elementosSeleccionados.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Y finalmente mi JSP:**

```
<table id="laboratorio" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
  style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>N°</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
      <th>Mineral</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>N° Paleta</th>
      <th><strong>Enviar</strong></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>N°</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Fecha Ingreso</th>
      <th>Mineral</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>N° Paleta</th>
      <th><strong>Enviar</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <s:iterator value="listaLiquiAcopios" var="lr" status="number">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#number.count"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#lr.clientes"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#lr.fecha"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#lr.centroacopio"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#lr.adelanto"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>
          <s:property value="#lr.placa"></s:property>
        </td>
        <td>

          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="numlote" value="<s:property value=" #lr.numlote">
              </s:property>" >
              <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"></span>
              </span>
            </label>
          </div>

        </td>

      </tr>
    </s:iterator>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "Lo debería convertir". Eso sólo ocurre si tu cadena es una representación de un Array de JSON, pero si es sólo un JSON entonces no podrás convertirlo a Array. Esto es una representación de Array de JSON: `[{"key": "value"}]` y esto otro es un JSON: `{"key": "value"}`. Ves la diferencia? Uno es simplemente un objeto dentro de un Array y el otro es un objeto solo. Asegúrate de enviar un Array si quieres convertirlo directamente, sino, pues has el discriminante al recibirlo. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razon, estaba enviando un json, ya lo solucione cambiando la libreria y modificando mi codigo. Gracias!